# Is there anyway to get IN Statement successful match index in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this SQL request:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Datas 
WHERE value IN (20,10,50,100,40)
```

I was wondering if it was possible to get the index of the match in the Array of the IN Statement.

For example, the request would return the row having the value 20, but I would like to get 0, the index of 20 in the IN Statement array.

Comment: Do you mean the index of the `IN (20,10,50,100,40)`?  I don't think there is.

Comment: No, not using `IN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can transform this array to a comma delimited string like `'20,10,50,100,40'` then you can use the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(value, '20,10,50,100,40') - 1
FROM Datas
```

I subtracted `1` from the function's result because you seem to want `0` based results.

Comment: @MadBrother33 did you accept and unaccept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

While you can't get the index of the match within an `IN` clause, you can use a stored procedure to create a temporary table with the values that you are matching and an index column, then simply `INNER JOIN` with your temporary table to retrieve the records and their index.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, maybe my suggestion wasn't clear: If the list is sent as a parameter to a SP, then it can be used to create a temp table with an index column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
select value , rank from (
SELECT value, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM Datas, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
       ) a where value IN (20,10,50,100,40)
```

Comment: why should OP "try this query"? rows are not guaranteed to be in a particular order. what if there is just one row returned, and that row has 50 as a value. this query may answer some question, but it doesn't answer the question asked by OP.